# Whats the difference between the following 2 blocks of code in JAVA

Tags: java, object, int

Whats the difference between using

```
Object example1 = 3;
System.out.println(example1);
```

and

```
int example2 = 3;
System.out.println(example2);
```

Both print `3`, so what is the difference between using `int` and `Object`?

Comment: I will treat it as an Object. It will then call `example1.toString()` to get String value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`3` is an `int`, one of the native types in Java.

If you assign it to `Object` it is *auto-boxed* into an `Integer` which is a regular class.

Therefore the difference is that in the first case you have in instance of the `Integer` class stored in a variable of type `Object`. In the second case you have a primitive `int` variable.

Answer (score 1):

The first block wraps the literal value `3` in an `Integer` object.
While the second one assigns the literal value `3` to an `int` variable.

Both blocks should output `3`, there is nothing weird about that.